# Trying to create a method that uses an outside object for a PostgreSQL query

Tags: java, postgresql

I am working on a personal project where I am trying to come up with a password storage system.
 Where I am currently stuck is the portion where I am trying to enter in the website, username, and password into a login database.

This is what I have so far:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Database {
private Properties connectionProps = new Properties();
private Connection conn = null;
private final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:postgresql:pswdmgr";

public Database(){
    connectionProps.put("user", "******");
    connectionProps.put("password", "*******");
}

public void addLogin(Login login){
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL,connectionProps)){
        String userName = user.getUserName();
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT into public.user_passwords (user_id,site_name,username, password) values (?,?,?,?)");
        PreparedStatement id = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM public.users WHERE username = ?");
        id.setString(1,userName);
        ResultSet rs = id.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()) {
            stmt.setInt(1, rs.getInt(1));
            stmt.setString(2, login.getWebsite());
            stmt.setString(3, login.getLoginUserName());
            stmt.setString(4, login.getLoginPswd());
            stmt.executeUpdate();
        }
    } catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

}

public int getUserId(User user) {
    int anInt = 0;
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, connectionProps)) {
        String userName = user.getUserName();
        PreparedStatement id = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id FROM public.users WHERE username = ?");
        id.setString(1, userName);
        ResultSet rs = id.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            anInt = rs.getInt(1);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(2);
    }
    return anInt;
}

public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {

    return conn;
}
}
```

This is my Login class where I am trying to add a user's login information into the user_password database. I have a separate User class that stores the username and password and creates a unique id for user's initial login to my application. My keys in both the user database and the user_password database is the id.

However, I cannot seem to figure out a way to pull id from the User class table into the addLogin method.

I am not sure if this is possible or not, but I am a bit of a newbie to Java so I am open to any suggestions.

If anyone needs me to go further to explain what I am trying to accomplish, please let me know.